# Trying to make master-detail charts in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, callback, react-hooks

I'm trying to replicate this example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail but with React (+Hooks).
My trouble is with the detailChart because I already got the master to work, I know that the detailChart will be generated by callback (I'm still not very good at the callbacks concept).
In the Highcharts documentation says I can make a callback function in chart.events.load, which is what I decided to do in the masterChart.
However I'm getting an error in the createDetails function (the callback function) saying

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'masterChart.series[0]')
```

which is weird because I do the same when creating the masterChart and it worked, so the problem can't be my RData object I think.

This is my code by now:

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import RData from '../data/RData'

const RChart = () =>  {
    const[masterChart,setMasterChart] = useState([]);
    const[detailChart,setDetailChart] = useState([]);

    //updating masterChart
    useEffect(()=>{
        setMasterChart({
            chart: {
                reflow: false,
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                marginLeft: 50,
                marginRight: 20,
                zoomType: 'x',
                events: {

                    // listen to the selection event on the master chart to update the
                    // extremes of the detail chart
                    selection: function (event) {
                        var extremesObject = event.xAxis[0],
                            min = extremesObject.min,
                            max = extremesObject.max,
                            detailData = [],
                            xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

                        // reverse engineer the last part of the data
                        RData.each(this.series[0].RData, function () {
                            if (this.x > min && this.x < max) {
                                detailData.push([this.x, this.y]);
                            }
                        });

                        // move the plot bands to reflect the new detail span
                        xAxis.removePlotBand('mask-before');
                        xAxis.addPlotBand({
                            id: 'mask-before',
                            from: RData[0][0],
                            to: min,
                            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                        });

                        xAxis.removePlotBand('mask-after');
                        xAxis.addPlotBand({
                            id: 'mask-after',
                            from: max,
                            to: RData[RData.length - 1][0],
                            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2)'
                        });


                        detailChart.series[0].setData(detailData);

                        return false;
                    },
                    load:createDetail(masterChart) //callback!!
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            accessibility: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                showLastTickLabel: true,
                maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
                plotBands: [{
                    id: 'mask-before',
                    from: RData[0][0],
                    to: RData[RData.length - 1][0],
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                }],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                min: 0.6,
                showFirstLabel: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 255],
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, 'rgba(0,255,255,0)']
                        ]
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: RData[0][0],
                data: RData
            }],

            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        })
    },[]);

    //callback function to create detail chart
    const createDetail = (masterChart) => {
        // prepare the detail chart
        var detailData = [],
        detailStart = RData[0][0];

        //Error here
        RData.each(masterChart.series[0].RData, function () {
            if (this.x >= detailStart) {
                detailData.push(this.y);
            }
        });

        setDetailChart({
            chart: {
                marginBottom: 120,
                reflow: false,
                marginLeft: 50,
                marginRight: 20,
                style: {
                    position: 'absolute'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historical USD to EUR Exchange Rate',
                align: 'left'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Select an area by dragging across the lower chart',
                align: 'left'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                maxZoom: 0.1
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var point = this.points[0];
                    return '<b>' + point.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A %B %e %Y', this.x) + ':<br/>' +
                        '1 USD = ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2) + ' EUR';
                },
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                radius: 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointStart: detailStart,
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                data: detailData
            }],

            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
    }


    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={masterChart} />
            <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={detailChart} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
} 

export default RChart;
```

I'm open to any criticism and better ways to this.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited) Try adding setMasterChart and setDetailChart in the empty array as the second argument of your effect hook. Just an idea.

Comment: It didn't help for now, why did you think that helps? Is it because when the state is set for the master chart it would help render the details chart?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better approach is to set Hooks options into one functional Component and pass them as a props into the functions which will render each chart.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lwkgkv?file=index.js